# how to open different levels from another scene?(unity 2d)

Tags: unity-game-engine

So currently I need to open different levels(they are on the same scene) from another scene. I want to enable sript for 1st level and disable scripts for others when user open first level from menu. But it didn't really work. So is there any way to enable/disable scripts from another scene? Or probably there is more sense to place every level on different scences?(I'm not sure that some systems like coins count will work properly.) thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put every levels on different scene, then load them Async

```
SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

then unload then previous one, when you don't need it anymore.

you can disable script from another scene, either you need to have a reference to them or Find them first, then disable the script.